# Big Query: Query Failed. Dataset Not Found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Guys I imported a table from .csv to my dataset in a project.
Then I preview my table it's shown, but whenever I ran query table, it always responded with

`Query Failed
Error: Not found: Dataset <project-id>:<table-name>. Please verify that the dataset exists and the correct location was used for the job.`

Here's my query
`SELECT distinct(customer_id) as cust_id FROM [<project-id>:<table-name>.orders] LIMIT 1000`

Is there anything wrong?
Or how should I query an imported table?

Comment: If you use the GUI, select the table and the use the "Query" option, it should show you how to select the table name. You can compare that to what you have written.

Comment: Yes I did that. But that was responded from BigQuery UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question, I see that you are using as table name `<project-id>:<table-name>`, but as you can see in [this documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#project-qualified_table_names), the correct naming for project-qualified table definitions is the following:

```
#legacySQL
[PROJECT_ID:DATASET.TABLE]

#standardSQL
`PROJECT_ID.DATASET.TABLE`
```

I see you are using Legacy SQL (by the usage of square brackets `[ ]`), so you should go with the first naming definition, but you are missing the dataset name between the project and the table.

Additionally, I see you are appending `orders` to the table name, but it is not clear what that is, given that you hid the table name as `<table-name>`.

---

Additionally, make sure that, if your dataset is not located in the US or EU, you specify the location when running the query, as explained in [this entry in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-locations#specifying_your_location).

Comment: I already changed to `SELECT * FROM `<project_id>.<dataset>.<table-name>` LIMIT 1000`
But still same error.

Is it need configs for uploading or creating data in same region as my GCE region?

Comment: Where is your dataset located? You can see it in the [BigQuery UI](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com), by clicking on the dataset you are trying to query. Then, when running the query, you can specify the location as explained in [this entry in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-locations#specifying_your_location), to be the same as where your dataset is located. Unless the dataset is located in Asia, there should be no need to specify the location, but it is worth trying in any case.

Comment: Wow, thats the answer. I don't realize that I need to set it manually. Thanks man!
I still have a lot of questions in BigQuery. Are you wouldn't mind been asked by me?

Comment: I am glad to hear that specifying the location worked for you! I presume your dataset was located in Asia in the end. Following [Stack Overflow best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you should keep different issues in different posts, but feel free to write new BigQuery questions in different posts and the community (including me) will be glad to help.